# Get access to the default LineStyleOrder and ColorOrder arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Quick "convenience" question for MATLAB users. I am looping over a plot command, passing it different data to plot each time. The data happens to be generated from a function call, which upon each iteration is passed a different parameter value. To plot everything on the same axis I am using the 'hold' function. Unfortunately this doesn't auto cycle through the available ColorOrder and/or LineStyleOrder plot parameters, so every line plotted has the same style on every iteration.

```ml
for i=1:nLines
    [x_data y_data]=get_xy_data(param1(i),param2(i))
    plot(x_data,y_data)
end
```

Every line plotted will be the default blue line style. 
The obvious solution is to generate up front a cell array of the various line styles, and colors as in:

```ml
line_styles={'-','--','-*'}; %...etc
colors=colormap(jet(nLines));
```

then access each of those on every iteration. What I want is access to the default colors which will be generated from ColorOrder, and the default line cycling, which comes from LineStyleOrder. If I try something like:

```ml
get(gca,'LineStyleOrder')
```

This only returns the styles used in that axis (I've only tested this on an axis defined with one of the styles, but point is, it doesn't give me all possible linestyles). Help appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Let me be more specific in what I am looking for.

```ml
figure; hold on;
for i=1:nLines
    [xdata, ydata]=get_data(p1(i),p2(i))  % call some function to return x,y data
    plot(xdata,ydata) % on i=1, default blue line

    % function which tells matlab to get/set the next linestyle, color combination          
    nextStyle()       
end
```

If this doesn't exist, it wouldn't be too hard to write it, but I thought I'd ask first before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in setting the default properties of `DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder` and `DefaultAxesColorOrder`.

The plots (style and color) will first loop through the newly defined colors and then changed the line style. In a successive plot loop, using `hold all` will "hold the graph and the current line color and line style so that subsequent plotting commands do not reset the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder" (see the [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)). Both examples produce identical results.

```
%default properties (line style and color)  
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder',{'--','-',':'})  
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder', summer(4))  

figure('Color','w');  

%example plot 1 (concurrent plots)  
subplot(1,2,1);  
yvals = [1:50;1:50]  
plot(yvals, 'LineWidth', 2)  
axis([1 2 0 size(yvals,2)+1 ]);  
title('concurrent plot','FontSize',16);  

%example plot 2 (iterative plots)
subplot(1,2,2);  
for ii = 1:50  
    plot(yvals(:,ii), 'LineWidth', 2);  
    hold all;  
end  
axis([1 2 0 size(yvals,2)+1 ]);  
title('successive plot','FontSize',16);
```

The results are

[image]

It looks like @Luis Mendo was not that wrong!

Comment: I understand when plotting a vector it auto cycles through the (now modified) LineStyleOrder and ColorOrder, and I get how to set those. However when plotting one line of data then another in a subsequent iteration using the `hold` command it does not autocycle. That is my question.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it wright. Please see my edited post. I added a second example using hold all in a successive plot situation.

Comment: Looks like that works! The disconnect was that you need to manually set the `DefaultLineStyleOrder` when using `hold all`, which you mentioned above. Thanks! I would upvote if I could...

Comment: Thank you, @Magla! Actually, I have never used `hold all` except for a quick test. I learned about it only two days ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hold all`. That automatically sets different colors and linestyles for each plot.

Comment: `hold all` only sets the colors, not line styles

Comment: Using ''hold all'' seems to cycle through the ColorOrder, but not LineStyleOrder. ColorOrder only has 7 possible colors in it so this leads to repeats.

Comment: one need to set the default properties of matlab in order to cycle through linestyles and colors. +1 for @Luis Mendo

Answer (score 1):

You could set the line style and color directly for each line.  Here's an example:

```
figure
hold on
nLines = 12;

line_styles={'-','--','-.'};
colors= hsv(nLines);
indexColors = 1;
indexLines = 1;

for i=1:nLines
    xData = 1:10;
    yData = rand(1,10);
    h = plot(xData,yData);

    ls = line_styles{indexLines};
    c = colors(indexColors,:);

    set(h,'color',c)
    set(h,'LineStyle',ls)

    if indexColors < length(colors)
        indexColors = indexColors + 1;
    else
        indexColors = 1;
    end

    if indexLines < length(line_styles)
        indexLines = indexLines + 1;
    else
        indexLines = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that is basically what I am doing now. My question was is there a way to just let MATLAB know that I want to cycle to the next color/line pair.